# Expand canvas or place a plot on a canvas

Tags: plotting

I need to place a complete plot (with axes, graphs etc.) on a larger canvas (or expand the canvas for an existing graph) but I cannot find the correct commands/syntax for it. Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

E.g. I have a graph that is 500x500 px

```
 H = Plot[{x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, ImageSize -> 500, AspectRatio -> Full]
```

but when I export this to JPEG file I want the canvas to be 600 high and 1340 wide, with the graph centered in the middle. Is this possible? TIA.

Comment: maybe `ImageMargins`:, e.g. `Plot[{x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ImageMargins -> Scaled[.2]]`?

Comment: ... or `ImageMargins -> {{#, #} &@(1340 - 500)/2, {#, #} &@(600 - 500)/2}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option [`ImageMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMargins.html).

Using an example with smaller numbers:

```
size = {550, 320}; is = 200;
Plot[{x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, ImageSize -> is, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ImageMargins -> {{#, #} &@(size[[1]] - is) / 2, {#, #} &@(size[[2]] - is)/2}]
```

[image]

Use `size = {1340, 600}; is = 500;` to get your desired result.

Comment: Many thanks, just what I wanted! I cannot seem to find information what unit length is used when I set the ImageSize. Is it mm or pixels or...?

Comment: @mf67, [ImageSize >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageSize.html) says it is in _printer points_.